# Identification of species found in fly lab

Tags: species-identification

I just found this in my *Drosophila* lab (within a closed vial) - unfortunately it was dead having been frozen for two weeks. Can anyone help **id what it is**, and **whether it poses a risk to my flies** (like mites do)? My inclination is that it is some kind of (moth?) larvae. Note the awesome corkscrew tail...

Found in Uppsala, Sweden, May 2014 in a vial of *Drosophila* with food (a yeast, sugar, and agar mix). Length is about 3-4mm excl. tail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd guess it's a [larva](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Dermestidae%20Larva) of one of the carpet beetles ([Dermestidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae)), some of which are synanthropic. They probably would be interested not in live flies, but in their food and cadavers.

Its appearance seems to be very characteristic - someone would be able to identify it to generic or even specific level.

Comment: *Attagenus* gebus is known for having longer tails than other dermestid beetles. See [Orkin](https://www.orkin.com/other/beetles/carpet-beetles/larvae), for example.